# Searching hashtable not working, for loop not executing in c

Tags: c, search, for-loop, hash, hashtable

I have a hashtable with separetaly linked lists. I Successfully store my elements in the hashtable but it fails when I try to search for my stored elements. My function `lookup_string` is supposed to find the right list in the hashtable and go through the linked list with the for-loop if more than one element is stored with the same hash-key.

Inside the `lookup_string` function I found out that the for-loop never executes (I used prints to check that) and the function skips that for-loop and returns NULL directly. This behaviour is really odd and I don't know why it skips that loop, but this is the reason why I can't find my elements after I have stored them, atleast what I think.

If someone can shed some light on this problem that would be much appreciated!

I have functions to delete elements in the hashtable but those are not necessary to consider, I just uploaded them for understanding purpose. I choose alternative 1 in the menu to add one element and then alternative 3 in the menu and that is when I can't find my stored element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct post                 // structure of node
{       
    char name[30];          // stored data
    int tel;                // stored data
    struct post *next;      // reference to next node
};

typedef struct post Post;   // Post = struct post

struct list
{
    Post *head;         
    Post *current;              
};

typedef struct list List;

struct hash_table
{
    List *table;
    int size;
};

typedef struct hash_table Post_table;

Post* CreateList(char tempname[30], int temptel)
{   
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);    
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    printf("\n creating list with headnode as [%s]\n",tempname);

    return ptr;
}

Post* AddList(char tempname[30], int temptel, Post *current)
{
    if( current == NULL )
    {
        return (CreateList(tempname, temptel));
    }

    printf("\n Adding node to end of list with value [%s]\n",tempname);
    Post *ptr = (Post*)malloc(sizeof(Post));

    strcpy(ptr->name, tempname);
    ptr->tel = temptel;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    current->next = ptr;

    return ptr;
}

unsigned int Hash(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    int i, sum, key;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(tempname); i++)
    {
        sum += (int)tempname[i];
    }

    key = abs(sum % hash_table->size);
    return key;
}

Post_table *create_hash_table(int size)
{
    Post_table *new_table;

    if (size < 1)
    {return NULL;}

    // attempt to allocate memory for the table structure
    if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(Post_table))) == NULL)
    {return NULL;}

    // attempt to allocate memory for the table itself
    // calloc() = all head and current are initialized with NULL
    if ((new_table->table = calloc(size,sizeof(List *) * size)) == NULL)
    {return NULL;}

    new_table->size = size;
    return new_table;
}

Post *lookup_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *list;
    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);
    printf("testprint-1");

    // Go to the correct list based on the hash value and see if str is
    // in the list.  If it is, return return a pointer to the list element.
    // If it isn't, the item isn't in the table, so return NULL.
    for(list = hash_table->table[hashkey].head; list != NULL; list = list->next)
    {
        printf("testprint-2");
        if (strcmp(tempname, list->name) == 0)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int add_string(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], int temptel)
{    
    Post *current_list;

    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);
    printf("\nHash-key: %d\n", hashkey);

    // if item already exists, don't insert it again
    current_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);
    if (current_list != NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    hash_table->table[hashkey].current = AddList(tempname, temptel, hash_table->table[hashkey].current);

    // if the list has been created just now, then both head and current must point to the only list element
    if( hash_table->table[hashkey].head == NULL )
    {
        hash_table->table[hashkey].head = hash_table->table[hashkey].current;
    }
    return 0;
}

void free_entry(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30])
{
    Post *del_list;
    Post *temp;
    int ret = 0;

    unsigned int hashkey = Hash(hash_table, tempname);
    del_list = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);
    ret = Delete(hash_table, tempname, hashkey);

    if(ret != 0)
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n delete [name = %s]  passed \n",tempname);
    }
}

void skrivMeny(void)
{
    printf("\n1: Register name and telephone number\n");
    printf("2: Remove name and telephone number\n");
    printf("3: Search for name\n");
    printf("5: Exit\n");
}

Post* Search(Post_table *hash_table, unsigned int hashkey, char tempname[30], Post **prev)
{
    Post *ptr = hash_table->table[hashkey].head;
    Post *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char structname[sizeof(tempname)];

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",tempname);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {   
        if (strcmp(ptr->name, tempname) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
    {
        if(prev)
        {
            *prev = tmp;
        }
        return ptr;
    }

    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int Delete(Post_table *hash_table, char tempname[30], unsigned int hashkey)
{
    Post *prev = NULL;
    Post *del = NULL;

    printf("\n Deleting value [%s] from list\n",tempname);
    del = Search(hash_table, hashkey, tempname, &prev);

    if(del == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    else
    {
        if(prev != NULL)
        {
            prev->next = del->next;
        }

        if(del == hash_table->table[hashkey].current && del != hash_table->table[hashkey].head)
        {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].current = prev;
        }

        else if(del == hash_table->table[hashkey].head)
        {
            hash_table->table[hashkey].head = del->next;
        }
    }

    free(del);
    del = NULL;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    printf("\nHej och välkommen till hashlistan\n\n");
    int menyval = 1;
    char tempname[30];
    int temptel, key;

    Post * ptr;

    Post_table *hash_table;
    int table_size = 10;
    hash_table = create_hash_table(table_size);

    while (menyval > 0 && menyval <= 5)
    {
        skrivMeny();
        scanf("%d", &menyval);

        if (menyval == 1)
        {
            printf("[Name] [Number] = ");
            scanf("%s %d", &tempname[0], &temptel);
            add_string(hash_table, tempname, temptel);
        }

        if (menyval == 2)
        {    
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            free_entry(hash_table, tempname);
        }

        if (menyval == 3)
        {
            printf("[Name] = ");
            scanf("%s", &tempname[0]);
            ptr = lookup_string(hash_table, tempname);

            if(ptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n Search [name = %s] failed, no such element found\n",tempname);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n Search passed [name = %s tel = %d]\n",ptr->name, ptr->tel);
            }
        }

        if (menyval == 5)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR. <!-- 15 chars -->

Comment: This website is for specific problems, not bug hunts.  Please find the exact area of your program that you don't understand, and ask a specific question with a definable answer. Thank you

Comment: To debug your problem, you need more information. Ask yourself: "How do I verify that the strings I wanted to insert into the hash table actually got inserted?" When you are able to answer that question, and then actually do the verification, you will be a step closer to solving this problem yourself.

Comment: There are two escape routes from the function that are not protected by `printf()` statements.  That it doesn't enter the loop means that the pointer is null.  You need to work out why your creation code is not doing its job as you expect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that could be the problem is that in your `Hash` function, you declare `sum` without initializing it to 0. My guess is that the for loop does not execute in 'lookup_string' because 'list' is NULL to begin with, as what 'Hash' won't necessarily be the same every time you call it (even with the same arguments).

Perhaps instead of:

```
int i, sum, key;
```

Put:

```
int i, key, sum = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much puppyofkosh! You are a very helpful person. I did not know the importance of initializing a variable during the declaration until now. I have always been confused about why sometimes people chose to initialize and sometimes they don't.